# What are the equivalents of date() for month and hour?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm using Ruby on rails 4.2, and SQLite.

I know that I can use the following code to group the records by the day `created_at`, Then sum the totals of each group to return a hash of each day's total:

```
Order.group("date(created_at)").select("created_at, sum(total) as total")
```

I wonder if there are equivalents of this **date()** function for **Year, Month, Hour** ?

And if not what are my best options to group records, Without using gems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`cast`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr) is what you're looking for with SQLite.

```
Order.where("cast(strftime('%Y', created_at) as int) = ?", year)
Order.where("cast(strftime('%m', date_column) as int) = ?", month)
Order.where("cast(strftime('%d', date_column) as int) = ?", day_of_month)
```

As to grouping (**EDIT**):

```
# group by year
Order.group("strftime('%Y', created_at)").select("created_at, sum(total) as total")
# group by month
Order.group("strftime('%m', created_at)").select("created_at, sum(total) as total")
# group by day
Order.group("strftime('%d', created_at)").select("created_at, sum(total) as total")
```

Comment: error `undefined local variable or method `year' for main:Object`

Comment: @MoatazZaitoun really? maybe you consider putting real integer (like `2016`) instead of `undefined local variable or method year`? :)

Comment: But I don't know which year I want to group by, I want to group each year's records by it's own

Comment: Thank you very much, But is considered a good practice -performance wise-?

Comment: @MoatazZaitoun I never saw sqlite used as a real-production database. But as to performance - if you use db to do things that could be done on the db layer - you can be sure you that it's a good decision and a good practice. Because making things using right tools can't be wrong :)